# CSS Position Different in FF and IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, firefox, css-position

I am trying to position some elements on a page at absolute positions. I used the following test code (I replaced the <> with [] to get through the HTML cleaner):

```
<body>
  <div style="position=absolute; top=100px; left=100px"> HELLO 100,100</div>
  <div style="position=absolute; top=200px; left=100px"> HELLO 200,100</div>
  <div style="position=absolute; top=0px; left=0px"> HELLO 0,0</div>
</body>
```

This does what it is apparently supposed to do in IE, but simply flows the divs one below each other in FF (3.0). I know CSS support is pretty variable. What am I missing, and is there a more standard way to do this?

Comment: @Jessica - You don't need to change your code to avoid parsing issues... simply indent each line of code with 4 spaces (after a clear line) and the formatter will do the rest for you. ;-) See here for full details on how to use Markdown (the system used here) http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 5):

The problem is your CSS syntax.

Instead of:

```
position=absolute;
```

put

```
position: absolute;
```

If you want absolute positioning within another tag, set the outer tag to be relatively positioned:

```
<div style="position:relative;">
  <div style="position:absolute;bottom:0;right:0;">
    This will be positioned in the bottom-right of the outer div.
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the = with :

```
<div style="position:absolute; top:100px; left:100px"> HELLO 100,100</div>
<div style="position:absolute; top:200px; left:100px"> HELLO 200,100</div>
<div style="position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px"> HELLO 0,0</div>
```